# How do i access and store two dimension list value in scala?

Tags: scala, list, arraylist

In Scala Programming Language, how does one store the value of the two dimensional list?

```
var lists = List[List[Double]]
```

How do i assign the value to it in a way like

```
lists(0)(1) = 0.4
```

When i try this way, it says

```
value update is not a member of List[Double]
```

What went wrong here, and how to make it right?
Thank you

Comment: ``List`` is immutable, ``Array`` is mutable so just change your type ``List`` with ``Array``.

Answer (score 2):

Like said in my comment, you cannot access to `n-th` element of list like you tried but it will works with an `Array` :

```
scala> val a = Array[Array[Double]](Array(1.2))
a: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.2))

scala> a(0)(0) = 1.1

scala> a
res16: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.1))
```

If you want to use a mutable List, use `ListBuffer` like below :

```
scala> val l = ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Double]](ListBuffer(1.1))
l: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Double]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1.1))

scala> l(0)(0) = 10.2

scala> l
res21: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Double]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(10.2))
```

Comment: Is there a way to use list instead of array?

Comment: In scala collection, you have a type called ``MutableLists`` if you want to use lists.

Comment: Well, but after reading about mutable list and immutable list, i would say in my case, it is preferrably immutable.
As i only need to read and store the data in a way so that it can be accessed easily.
And this data wont be changed..
Any suggestion on that? @alifirat

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a List, use the `updated` method which returns a new List with a single element updated.

```
val updatedLists = lists.updated(0, lists(0).updated(1, 0.4))
```

This looks pretty ugly, it's also a bad idea. You should reconsider your choice of datastructure. `List` is not a good choice if this is what you want to do. If you find yourself needing to do this or using List for anything other than `head`, `tail`, or `::` you probably don't want a `List` (`Vector` is usually a better default collection than `List` but that's not what this question is about).  Index based reads and especially updates are very slow for Lists and updates potentially require lots of object copying.  It just isn't the purpose of list to do this, they aren't designed for it.

Based on what you are trying to do, you almost certainly want an `Array` or `ArrayBuffer` like alifirat says.  Arrays are mutable are very efficient for random reads and updates.    If you are making updates, you want a mutable structure.  If you absolutely must have an immutable structure you can use `Vector` which allows for efficient random reads.  Random updates can be better then `List` but it's still not something you want to do that often.